# height: 100% for fixed sidebar but on mobile is behaving strange

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Im developing a website from scratch, my website is a "one-page" type, and my navigation menu make it scroll between sections using anchors.

I'm relatively new to mobile-optimized developing. Everything is fine on comptuer but when testing it in mobile-phone, when scrolling down manually, the sidebar that is supposed to be fixed, create a blank space below it for a second, after that it become again 100% height as it's supposed to be. I would like to remove that "blank space below sidebar" second delay, when scrolling.

Here's my example, try to browse it by mobile phone (i used iPhone actually).

http://www.officine06.com/limonaia

Full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/hQGFa

the CSS code:

`.sidebar {background: yellow; width: 200px; height: 100%;   position: fixed; z-index: 10; left: 0; top: 0;}`

I also noticed that the smoothscroll js is not working on mobile.
And if u look at the above hosted example with background photos, on mobile it creates a white space between the backgrounds of the sections, that's not supposed to happen.

Any suggestion would be very appreciated, thanks in advance, and sorry for my english, is not my native language.

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the space for the search/address bar of the iPhone's browser, infact when you scroll down it disappear and behave like a "header", and the sidebar's height:100%; property follows it, creating the bug when u release the finger while touching. I know, Im so bad in english xD, I hope it's clear anyway. The real issue is: "Why when i touch navigation links in the iPhone the page is not scrolling properly?" Have a look at the jsfiddle for the js.